# Two defective balls out of ten

Tags: probability, combinations

> There are 2 defective balls in a batch of 10. To inspect, someone will randomly check 2 balls to see if they're defective and will reject if at least 1 ball they check is defective.
>
> What's the probability of finding at least 1 defective ball when randomly selecting 2 from the batch of 10?

The solution should deal with permutations, but I'm not sure how to initially approach this.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: You mean "what is the probability that the batch gets rejected?"

Comment: Yes- what's the probability it gets rejected (what's the probability that randomly selecting 2 balls will give you at least 1 defective ball)

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  the number of ways you could get a defective ball is 
\begin{align}
\binom{2}{1}\binom{8}{1} + \binom{2}{2}\binom{8}{0}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a combinatorics problem, number the balls 1 to 10, with 1 and 2 defective. (The labelling is unimportant, but I find it a help when solving problems like this.)

The number of ways to choose *any* two balls is $\binom{10}2=45$. The number of ways to choose two *non-defective* balls is $\binom82=28$. Therefore the probability the batch gets rejected because at least one defective ball was selected is
$$1-\frac{28}{45}=\frac{17}{45}$$

Answer (score -1):

hey actually it is a quite easy question u dont need to worry
wat we have to do is select two balls out of 10 that is 10c2 which comes out to be 45 and then non defective once that is 8c2 which comes out to be 28
after doing this the probablity of non defctive comes out to be 28/45 and for non defctive just subtract from 1*here u r done*